# i'm trying to build a small power bank flashlight

Tags: voltage

I am wanting to make a power bank with two 18650 batteries and an led flashlight combination. I have this free light , [https://www.amazon.com/Ultra-Bright-Portable-Worklight-Flashlight/dp/B08189KYCG/ref=asc_df_B08189KYCG/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=416958783560&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=13539993788906158846&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9024398&hvtargid=pla-870946458439&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=89137678690&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=416958783560&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=13539993788906158846&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9024398&hvtargid=pla-870946458439](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08189KYCG) , It would fit the two 18650 batteries and I have a maker power
bank module , [https://www.amazon.com/Mobile-Battery-Charger-Module-Protection/dp/B07D6M2LCS/ref=pd_bxgy_img_3/134-5433051-3166302?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07D6M2LCS&pd_rd_r=8e86fb08-aa54-4b74-b1c9-62c0e164e869&pd_rd_w=2AgsA&pd_rd_wg=5hKkz&pf_rd_p=f325d01c-4658-4593-be83-3e12ca663f0e&pf_rd_r=EKF7Z42MYMPEBNHW0A5X&psc=1&refRID=EKF7Z42MYMPEBNHW0A5X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D6M2LCS) The light is 3AAA batteries and I'm wondering if I should step up .5to.8v directly from the 2x18650 battery to the lights directly, that I plan to leave in the flashlight, and how i would go about that, or if i should use resistance from the output on the power bank module to step down the voltage for the light circuit and or how to do this.
any tips would be very appreciated.
ps. I am very new to this but electrical engineering has always been something I wished to learn well and I now have the time to start learning and want to start small and am so appreciative I found this site today. :)

Comment: This kind of thing is typically not a good place to start a learning project.  To have an answerable question, you're going to need to "edit" this to give clear specifications of the parts, *not sales links*.  It's entirely possible that the parts you are contemplating for this purpose are not suitable or compatible with each other.  Typically one would buy a full solution to this problem, and conduct learning projects in more traditional low power logic, etc areas.

Comment: Thank you @Chris Stratton for your input. i have made a few bread board blinking lights and stuff. i just figured the led light circuits would be ubiquitous and maybe someone else would have started with a similar project or where they just needed a few pointers. If I do figure this out I will be very excited to post what i did to get this to work.

Comment: @NathanW This is not starting small; a power bank with appropriate protection to make sure it doesn't explode, burst into flames, or spray toxic electrolyte all over the place is a complicated project and there are many ways it can go wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your concern @Hearth I have made 2 (ugly) power banks with the listed power bank modules from maker. For this one I wanted to properly place it in this flashlight that has a clear front perfect for the led display and is mostly empty which is why i can place the 2 18650 batteries i have into it. i can easily make the power bank like i did my others in here i just wanted to incorporate the led flashlight circuit and switch and was looking for information included in the post. Sorry if I came off as reckless here.